# Using Beautiful soup to find a phone number for company name and address

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-search

I have a script which scrapes a website for the name, region and province of companies in Spain. There is another link within the html, which takes you to a page that contains the phone number, but when I try to even scrape the html, it prints "none". Is there a way that the script can automatically move to the page, scrape the number and match it with the company row?

```
import requests
from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for page in range(1,65):
    url = "https://www.expansion.com/empresas-de/ganaderia/granjas-en-general/{page}.html".format(page =page)

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    lists = soup.select("div#simulacion_tabla ul")

#scrape the list
    for lis in lists:
        title = lis.find('li', class_="col1").text
        location = lis.find('li', class_="col2").text
        province = lis.find('li', class_="col3").text
        link = lis.find('href', class_ ="col1")
        info = [title, location, province, link]
print(info)
```

Alternatively, is there is a way to do it with googlesearch library?

Many thanks

Comment: How do you get your data from the second link? Are you creating a new request or do you just try to parse it with bs4? This information is not visible from your question.

Comment: ohh right, that makes sense. I was trying to do it all in one. I will have to create a second request to get the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first url `"https://www.expansion.com/empresas-de/ganaderia/granjas-en-general/index.html"` not

```
"https://www.expansion.com/empresas-de/ganaderia/granjas-en-general/1.html"
```

for this reason your script does not return output.

you can try like this

```
import requests
# from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
baseurl = ["https://www.expansion.com/empresas-de/ganaderia/granjas-en-general/index.html"]

urls = [f'https://www.expansion.com/empresas-de/ganaderia/granjas-en-general/{i}.html'.format(i) for i in range(2,5)]


allurls = baseurl + urls
print(allurls)


for url in allurls:

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    lists = soup.select("div#simulacion_tabla ul")

    #scrape the list
    for lis in lists:
        title = lis.find('li', class_="col1").text
        location = lis.find('li', class_="col2").text
        province = lis.find('li', class_="col3").text
        link = lis.select("li.col1 a")[0]['href']
        info = [title, location, province, link]
        print(info)
```

Comment: Hi Samsul, this still returns "none" for the link variable. I believe the problem is in that line. --> link = lis.find('href', class_ ="col1")

Comment: try it .link = lis.select("li.col1 a")[0]['href']

Comment: Yep, that works! I can´t seem to edit the script to approve it as a correct solution. If you can I will do that for you. Many thanks!